# Get specific color from admin color scheme

Tags: plugin-development

I know how to print the **current color scheme** by using:

```
echo get_user_option( 'admin_color', get_current_user_id() );
```

or

```
echo get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'admin_color', true);
```

but I need to print a **specific color of this scheme**. In other words I want the $colors array of this function:

```
<?php wp_admin_css_color( $key, $name, $url, $colors, $icons ); ?>
```

I have to use colors in the setting page of my plugin but I want to be coherent. Any solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I need to know the four colors of the color scheme. I know my colors now but I want the colors to change dynamically within the color scheme. This is for a setting page.

Comment: There is an example of the colors array [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_admin_css_color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color schemes are registered globally within `$_wp_admin_css_colors` (see [wp-includes/general-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2596) for reference).

You can return the colors for the current user depending on `get_user_meta()` for a specific settings page like this:

```
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'options-permalink.php' ) :
  add_action( 'admin_notices', 'get_current_user_admin_color' );
  function get_current_user_admin_color() {
    global $_wp_admin_css_colors;
    $user_admin_color = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'admin_color', true);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_wp_admin_css_colors[$user_admin_color]->colors);
    echo '</pre>';
  }
endif;
```

Feel free to vary the action hook to fit your needs: maybe `admin_notices` is to specific, so you may also try something like `admin_head`.

Moreover `$_wp_admin_css_colors[$user_admin_color]` is holding even more meta data about the current admin color scheme:

- `[name]` Name of the current admin color scheme
- `[url]` Absolute path to the current color scheme CSS file
- `[colors]` Colors of the current admin color scheme
- `[icon_colors]` Icon colors of the current admin color scheme